# Can I substitute regular dried lemon peel for sweetened dried lemon peel?

Tags: substitutions, lemon

I have a recipe for mini lemon-poppy seed bread that calls for purchased sweetened dried lemon peel (3 oz). Can I substitute dried lemon peel since I can't locate the sweetened? The recipe is for Mini Lemon-Poppy Seed Loaves from Cuisine at Home magazine. The 3 oz. (1/2 cup) lemon peel is mixed in with the flour mixture.

Comment: Please provide the recipe for context....if they really mean candied lemon peel, that would not be a great substitution.

Comment: WOW...Three ounces is A LOT!

Comment: @Jolenealaska Yes, that is what makes me think the intended ingredient is candied peel.

Comment: Even candied that's a lot, unless it's still hydrated.

Comment: it could be demi-sec to account for the weight, thought I don't know if I've seen demi-sec peels.

Comment: We get still-hydrated sweetened (but not hydrated) peel around here, Dr Oetker manufactures it. It is still used in small amounts, maybe 2-3 g per recipe, not 3x28 g.

Comment: If what you're looking for turns out to be candied lemon peel, any one of us can help you make it, it's easy. Show us the recipe, we can definitely help.

Comment: I found sweet lemon peel at a store called Reams. It was by mince meat and similar items. It is in a 8oz container. Made by Pennant fruit products, inc. In Florida. I want to make the same recipe. Good luck.

Comment: I am looking all over for the same ingredient for the very same recipe. I'm about to give up but I plan to write the magazine. In the past I have had a good response from my inquiries. This just doesn't make sense and I bake a lot!

Comment: Sweetened dried lemon peel is available at King Arthur Flour For about $10.

Comment: @Rosemary It looks like you're talking about what they call "European Lemon Zest"? They describe it as "Best-quality European lemon peel. Lightly sweetened, very finely grated peel."

Answer (score 2):

We made this recipe last night with Watkins Dried Lemon Peel, which we think was unsweetened. The bread did not come out well.